# Python3 using re.match to check if password hold certain characters

Tags: python, regex, match

I am trying to return the password entered by a user if it matches `a-z`,`A-Z`,`0-9`,`_`,`-` otherwise a ValueError will be executed within a try clause. Here is my line of code that doesn't seem to be working as it allows just about anything like (?.,@#$%^*)

```
return re.match('^[A-Za-z0-9_-]*$',password)
```

Comment: define _allows just about anything_ ... what exactly is it matching that you dont think it should?

Comment: Try this:`^[?!A-Za-z0-9_-]*$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Kleene closure, you allow an empty string as a correct password. You can use the `+` special character to match one repetitions of the valid characters:

```
def validate(password):
    match = re.match('^[a-z0-9_-]+$', password, re.I)
    if match is not None:
        return password
    else:
        raise ValueError
```

Comment: Looking at his `regex` I think `_-` are also allowed.

Comment: Huh, I had no idea the `*` in regex syntax was called a "Kleene closure" or ["Kleene star"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star) or that it came from mathematical notation. Learn something new every day. Just as well it's not a [Kleene X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleenex). :-)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Yes, but the OP specifically says _it matches a-z,A-Z,0-9_, which seems to be more concrete than a line of code that is not giving the result he expects.

Comment: @BenHoyt I became all too familiar with it in a Theory of Computation class.

Comment: Sorry yes _ and - should also be allowed

Answer (score 1):

## Outline

Using sets and set-subtraction is likely a simpler solution.

## Code

```
from string import ascii_letters, digits

PASSWORD_SET = set(ascii_letters + digits + "_-")

def has_only_password_letters(candidate):
    return not(set(candidate) - PASSWORD_SET)
```

or:

```
def has_only_password_letters(candidate):
    return all(c in PASSWORD_SET for c in candidate)
```

## Tests

```
>>> def test_password(password):
...     if has_only_password_letters(password):
...         print "Okay: ", password
...     else:
...         print "Nuh-uh: ", password
... 
>>> test_password("asdasd123123")
Okay:  asdasd123123
>>> test_password("asdasd123123!!!")
Nuh-uh:  asdasd123123!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-regex solution using `isalnum`:

```
for c in password:
    if not (c.isalnum() or c in ['_', '-']):
        raise ValueError('Invalid character in password')
```